# Checking if contents of a field were changed via a program. What event will be triggered

Tags: javascript, dom-events, unobtrusive-javascript

I have a password field that, because it has it's field name inside it, begins as an `input="text"`. When the user types or clicks on it, the field swaps out to `input="password"`.

Some of our users store their username/password into a 3rd party program. Because the password is being written into the field via one of their functions, my password field isn't swapping out to a password because there's no event firing against it.

The third party folks aren't on the ball and really just said, "tough".

I was thinking of doing a `setInterval` to check the contents, but this will not be immediate enough.

Does anyone if any event fires if the contents of an input field is changing via a function. Again, I have no control over the function that is inputting the password.

Any suggestions would be a help. I feel as if this is a lost cause. BTW, I can't use jQuery because it's not an approved technology on our site. But, if there is a jQuery solution, I can see what I can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your situation, you could reverse your logic.  You can start the field as "password", then on setTimeOut, check if it has a value of 'password'.  If it does, set it to "text".

(You could further use 'onchange' and backend validation to disallow the word `password` as a password)

Comment: Thanks but I can't do it that way. The field has to be a text because the word "password" has to be in it. Dumb, I know. I didn't design it and in fact, argued against it.

Comment: The onchange doesn't work because it still needs a user interaction. The password has to be concealed when the 3rd party software places the text into the box.

Comment: Right.. the field has to be text because, but more importantly *if*, the word "password" is in it.  It seems to me you could start the field as `password` type, and then upon load, if the field's value is "password", change its type to `text`.  Then, `onfocus` you set its type to `password` and clear it out.